# Get selected text from a drop-down list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this issue regarding jquery. 
I'm trying to test two paths:

```
it("should return true when country is valid", function() {
    var validCountry = "Germany";
    $("#fld_country option:selected").val(validCountry);

    expect(isValid("#fld_country")).toBeTruthy();
});

it("should return false when country is invalid", function() {
    var invalidCountry = "";
    $("#fld_country option:selected").val(invalidCountry);

    expect(isValid("#fld_country")).toBeFalsy();
});
```

`validCountry` and `invalidCountry` are options selected from a dropdown list.

This is the isValid function:

```
function isValid(selector) {
    if (selector === "#fld_country option:selected") {
        return validator.isSelectedField(selector);
    }
    else return validator.isFieldEmpty(selector);
}
```

and this is the `isSelectedField`:

```
isSelectedField: function (selector) {
        return $.trim($('selector option:selected').html())
```

Problem is it is failing due to :

```
validate registration form should return true when country is valid
```

and

```
validate registration form should return false when country is invalid FAILED
```

I don't know what the problem is... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isValid` function will always return `validator.isFieldEmpty(selector)` since the `selector` value won't match - you compare `#fld_country` to `#fld_country option:selected`. 
Maybe this is the issue.

//EDIT

OK. Make sure you're setting correct template. You mentioned you use jasmine-jquery fixtures. Before your test runs you could check if the select has any options.

I believe you're trying to set selected option via jquery - this has a bug, should be:

```
$("#fld_country").val(validCountry);
```

This will work if your `<select>` looks something like this (so again, check your templates)

```
<select id="fld_country">
  <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

The other issue you have is in `isSelectedField` function. Instead of

```
return $.trim($('selector option:selected').html())
```

you probably want to have something like:

```
return $.trim($(selector + ' option:selected').html())
```

because you want to use `selector` variable not the string.

Comment: I fixed it to it. Now is one test is failing due to: validate registration form should return true when country is valid FAILED. Expected '' to be truthy.

Comment: there is another issue, please check my answer now

Comment: I still have issues. I think is due to setting the fixtures... is this the right way: jasmine.getFixtures().set(' <input id="fld_email" type="text" >          \
                                <input id="fld_name" type = "text">\
                                <select id="fld_country" type = "text">\
                            ');
    }

Comment: I don't know what does jasmine.getFixtures do but I think you want to add select with some options, in particular with the 'Germany' value. For now looks like it is empty dropdown. 
Another issue is with setting the selected option, it should be

$("#fld_country").val(validCountry);

Comment: Yeah, but this is what you have in your code, we're not sure if the test see the same. Just do a console.log($("#fld_country option")) in your test to see if you have anything there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112074/discussion-between-apieceofbart-and-sofia).